# Buttons not appearing in GridPane JavaFX8

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, javafx-8

I am declaring buttons prior to using them inside the GridPane so I can use the button.setOnAction() function to switch scenes, but the buttons don't appear.

When I create the button inside the gridpane.add() function it works just fine. I've tried using BorderPanes instead and doing the non-lambda version of the EventHandler.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static Scene scene1;
    public static Scene scene2;
    public static Scene scene3;
    public static Scene[] scenes = new Scene[]{null, scene1, scene2, scene3};

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Scene Switcher");

        GridPane gp1 = new GridPane();
        GridPane gp2 = new GridPane();
        GridPane gp3 = new GridPane();

        Button button1 = new Button("scene 1");
        button1.setOnAction(event -> primaryStage.setScene(scene1));
        Button button2 = new Button("scene 2");
        button2.setOnAction(event -> primaryStage.setScene(scene2));
        Button button3 = new Button("scene 3");
        button3.setOnAction(event -> primaryStage.setScene(scene3));

        //
        // SCENE 1
        //
        Label l1 = new Label("this is scene 1");
        BorderPane.setAlignment(l1, Pos.CENTER);
        gp1.add(l1, 0, 0);
        gp1.add(button2, 0, 2);
        gp1.add(button3, 0, 3);
        scene1 = new Scene(gp1, 500, 500);

        //
        // SCENE 2
        //
        Label l2 = new Label("this is scene 2");
        BorderPane.setAlignment(l2, Pos.CENTER);
        gp2.add(l2, 0, 0);
        gp2.add(button1, 0, 2);
        gp2.add(button3, 0, 3);
        scene2 = new Scene(gp2, 500, 500);

        //
        // SCENE 3
        //
        Label l3 = new Label("this is scene 3");
        BorderPane.setAlignment(l3, Pos.CENTER);
        gp3.add(l3, 0, 0);
        gp3.add(button1, 0, 2);
        gp3.add(button2, 0, 3);
        scene3 = new Scene(gp3, 500, 500);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

The buttons don't show at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Button` nodes can only belong to one `GridPane` at a time. Here, you're adding them to `gp2` and `gp3` after adding them to `gp1`.

You'll need to rethink your design for this `Stage` as the way you're attempting to do it is not possible.

You can confirm this by commenting out all the code for scenes 2 & 3. The buttons will appear as they should.